# R plot(polygon) not showing different colors

Tags: r, plot, spatial

Why is this basic `R` plot not displaying each polygon in a different color?

```
text <- read.table(text="
name,long,lat,waterLevel,elevation,depth  
EM_01,18.553392,-34.07027,14.4,20.358,63.0  
EM_27,18.574777,-34.068709,16.196,19.966,48.0  
EM_29,18.613985,-34.053271,18.766,25.477,39.0  
EM_20,18.654089,-34.045177,20.102,36.502,45.0  
EM_23,18.643495,-34.037468,22.915,32.715,33.0  
EM_13,18.637267,-34.029194,25.516,29.716,33.0  
EM-14,18.625365,-34.018362,31.427,33.027,27.0", header=TRUE)
```

```r
library(sf) # 'simple features' representations of spatial objects

file = 'text.txt'

#-- import
cfaq <- read.csv(file, header = 1, sep = ',', dec = '.') 

#- set as a spatial feature with xy coords an existing projection
cfaq.sf <- st_as_sf(cfaq, coords=c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) #wgs84

#- transform to local crs
cfaq.sf <- st_transform(cfaq.sf, crs = 32734) #utm 34s
cfaq.sf$X <- st_coordinates(cfaq.sf)[, "X"]
cfaq.sf$Y <- st_coordinates(cfaq.sf)[, "Y"]

# Voronoi tesselation
pnts <- st_union(cfaq.sf)
voronoi_grid <- st_voronoi(pnts)
# Convert the voronoi grid to an sf dataframe
voronoi_df <- st_sf(geometry = voronoi_grid)
# Perform spatial join to associate waterLevel values
joined <- sf::st_join(voronoi_df, cfaq.sf)
head(joined, 3)

   name waterLevel elevation depth        X       Y                       geometry
1 EM_01     14.400    20.358    63 274221.5 6227351 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POLYGON...
2 EM_27     16.196    19.966    48 276191.3 6227571 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POLYGON...

plot(joined['waterLevel'])
```

[image]

Should each polygon not be in the color of the `waterLevel` value? Why is this plot not displaying correctly?